# Why is math.pow not natively able to deal with ints? (floor/ceil, too)

Tags: java, pow, floor, ceil

I know that in Java (and probably other languages), Math.pow is defined on doubles and returns a double. I'm wondering why on earth the folks who wrote Java didn't also write an int-returning pow(int, int) method, which seems to this mathematician-turned-novice-programmer like a forehead-slapping (though obviously easily fixable) omission. I can't help but think that there's some behind-the-scenes reason based on the intricacies of CS that I just don't know, because otherwise... huh?

On a similar topic, ceil and floor *by definition* return integers, so how come they don't return ints?

Thanks to all for helping me understand this. It's totally minor, but has been bugging me for years.

Comment: I think it comes down to the fact that CPU have special instructions to do Math.pow for floating point numbers (but not for integers).

Comment: For `Math.pow`, ints (and longs) can be converted to double, so they are taken care of automatically.

Comment: I would think they were just copying C's math.h.

Comment: @markspace: except, I do seem to have to cast any int to a double before my compiler will accept it...

Comment: Comes to mind that exponents of ints can get very big. BigInteger does offer exponent.

Comment: @Katie: yes, that was my point.  It happens automatically, no need to do anything at all.  Hence "automatically" in my comment above.

Comment: The real reason is that the market demand for floating point exponentiation is vastly greater than the demand for integer exponentiation in the upper ranges of the `long` type. And `BigInteger.pow` exists for larger integer needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java.lang.Math is just a port of what the C math library does.

For C, I think it comes down to the fact that CPU have special instructions to do Math.pow for floating point numbers (but not for integers).

Of course, the language could still add an `int` implementation. BigInteger has one, in fact. It makes sense there, too, because `pow` tends to result in rather big numbers.

> ceil and floor by definition return integers, so how come they don't return ints

Floating point numbers can represent integers outside of the range of `int`. So if you take a `double` argument that is too big to fit into an `int`, there is no good way for `floor` to deal with it.

Comment: Not all of it is JNI-glued btw. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StrictMath.java) for the default implementation. Take a look at `#round()` for example.

Answer (score 2):

From a mathematical perspective, you're going to overflow your integer if it's larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1, and overflow your long if it's larger than 2<sup>64</sup>-1.  It doesn't take much to overflow it, either.

Doubles are nice in that they can represent numbers from ~10<sup>-308</sup> to ~10<sup>308</sup> with 53 bits of precision.  There may be some fringe conversion issues (such as the next full integer in a double may not exactly be representable), but by and large you're going to get a much larger range of numbers than you would if you strictly dealt with integers or longs.

> On a similar topic, ceil and floor by definition return integers, so how come they don't return ints?

For the same reason outlined above - overflow.  If I have an integral value that's larger than what I can represent in a long, I'd have to use something that could represent it.  A similar thing occurs when I have an integral value that's smaller than what I can represent in a long.

Answer (score 2):

Optimal implementation of integer `pow()` and floating-point `pow()` are very different.  And C's math library was probably developed around the time when floating-point coprocessors were a consideration.  Optimal implementation of floating point operation is to shift the numbers closer to 1 (to force quicker conversion of the power series) and then shift the result back. For integer power, a more accurate result can be had in `O(log(p))` time by doing something like this:

```
// p is a positive integer power set somewhere above, n is the number to raise to power p
int result = 1;
while( p != 0){
    if (p & 1){ 
        result *= n;
    }
    n = n*n; 
    p = p >> 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all `int`s can be upcast to a `double` without loss and the `pow` function on a `double` is no less efficient that that on an `int`.

Comment: no less efficient computation-wise, okay, but readability/efficiency-of-typing-wise, it'd save a lot not to have *three* casts just to take 5^7 or whatever...

Comment: @Katie - Yes you have to cast the result if you must have an `int` but you don't need to cast the `int` parameters - they up-cast automagically. What if you get a `long` result or even bigger though? `(int)Math.pow(10,300)`

Comment: even if it's equally efficient, it doesn't mean it's equally accurate.

Answer (score -2):

The reason lies behind the implementation of [`Math.pow()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StrictMath.java#StrictMath.pow%28double%2Cdouble%29) (JNI of default implementation). The CPU has an exponentiation module which  works with doubles as input and output. Why should Java convert that for you when you have much better control over this yourself?

For floor and ceil the reasons are the same, but note that:

```
(int) Math.floor(d) == (int) d;   // d > 0
(int) Math.ceil(d) == -(int)(-d); // d < 0
```

For most cases (no warranty around or beyond `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`).

Java leaves you with

```
(int) Math.pow(a,b)
```

because the result of `Math.pow` may even be `NaN` or `Infinity` depending on input.

Comment: Why should Java do anything for you when you have control over it yourself?

Comment: @djechlin Well, in this particular case it wouldn't save you a single line of code...

Comment: In the second example you gave... does int-casting always round down? I thought it truncated (so that (int) (-4.5) would be -4). No?

Comment: @Katie Yeah neither of those lines are quite right.  Top one is valid for positive numbers and the bottom one for negatives.

Comment: @TavianBarnes ah, okay, that makes more sense, thanks

Comment: "Why should Java convert that for you when you have much better control over this yourself?" Well, yes, I can make it work by casting everything to doubles and then back to ints, but `a = Math.pow(c,d)` seems to me a whole lot more readable than `a = (int) Math.pow((double)c,(double)d)`, and it's also a lot less to type -- so that's why I'd expect java to do it for me.

Comment: @Katie confirmed the caveat. Note that `(int) Math.pow(c,d)` will be desugared into `(int) Math.pow((double) c, (double) d)` anyways, so no need to explicitly cast the arguments.

Comment: @AlexR int-casting does not round down, it truncates.  `(int) -4.5 == -4`.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that.e.g Math.pow(3,3) >= 27? Could you get Math.pow(3,3) = 26.999999996? That would be a strong case for an int- version.

Comment: djechlin: You are guaranteed that Math.pow(3,3) == 27. Just read the API documentation.

Comment: @djechlin Actually, a long time ago some intel processors had a [similar mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug) to what you fear, but this would be considered a hardware fault. If you want to get those on current processors, you can overclock them too much and have too low voltage + too low cooling, increasing the likelihood of such an error. ^^